# jquery else if statement issue with div:contains

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I'm having an issue where the DVD/Games and General items are being ignored and everything is flagged as a jewelry item as it's only reading the first if statement. What am I doing incorrectly? Is it an issue with the :contains? The first function makes it so it doesn't matter if DVD is lowercase, upper or mixed. Many thanks.

In this example. DVD should be found and then Game / DVD / Blu-Ray should be displayed in #biic-item-type instead of Jewellery

```js
              setTimeout(
                    function()
                    {
                        $.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
                            return function( elem ) {
                                return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
                            };
                        });
                        if ($("#content-body:contains('white gold'), #content-body:contains('yellow gold'), #content-body:contains('bracelet'), #content-body:contains('necklace'), #content-body:contains('charm'), #content-body:contains('pendant'), #content-body:contains('bangle'), #content-body:contains('diamond')").length) {
                            $('#marketing').append('<img id="tradeandsaveimage" src="chrome-extension://oglkppenbgclfdedmogeodheocmeeafa/images/advertising/Trade-and-Save-Logo.jpg?w=803&h=603" width="804" height="604" />');
                            $('#biic-item-type').text('Jewellery').addClass('bit-jewellery');
                        } else if ($("#content-body:contains('dvd'), #content-body:contains('game disc'), #content-body:contains('game cartridge'), #content-body:contains('blu-ray disc')").length) {
                            $('#marketing').append('<img id="tradeandsaveimage" src="chrome-extension://oglkppenbgclfdedmogeodheocmeeafa/images/advertising/Trade-and-Save-Logo.jpg?w=803&h=603" width="804" height="604" />');
                            $('#biic-item-type').text('Game / DVD / Blu-Ray').addClass('bit-dvd');
                        } else {
                            $('#marketing').append('<img id="warrantyimage" src="chrome-extension://oglkppenbgclfdedmogeodheocmeeafa/images/advertising/Warranty-90-Day-Logo.jpg?w=803&h=603" width="804" height="604" /><img id="tradeandsaveimage" src="chrome-extension://oglkppenbgclfdedmogeodheocmeeafa/images/advertising/Trade-and-Save-Logo.jpg?w=803&h=603" width="804" height="604" />');
                            $('#biic-item-type').text('General Stock').addClass('bit-general');
                        }
            
                    //    var descweightnext = $("#item-pre-description div p strong:contains('Weight')");
                    //    if (descweightnext.length) {
                    //      var bono = descweightnext.next('span').text();
                        
                    //    };
                    //    $('#item-weight').text(bono);
                    }, 500);
```

```css
div#biic-item-type {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    min-width: 86px !important;
    color: #fff;
    min-height: 16px;
    text-align: center
}
.bit-jewellery { background: #650080; }
.bit-dvd { background: #6161a3; }
.bit-general { background: #93102e; }
#content-body { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="biic-item-type"></div>
<div id="content-body">
            <div id="item-weight"></div>
          <div id="header-split-left">
            <div id="item-title">
                 This Is 40&nbsp;(000200195437)
            </div>
            <div id="item-category">
            DVD<br>            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="header-split-right">
            <div id="item-product-number-copy">
              000200195437            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="the-body-stats">
            <div id="item-price">
            $6<sup>.00</sup><br>            </div>
            <div id="description-paste-here">Product details:
Item Number: 000200195437
Title: This Is 40
Box Set: No
 </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have not closed the `<div id="content-body">`, its the cause of your problem

```js
setTimeout(
  function() {
    $.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
      return function(elem) {
        return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
      };
    });

    if ($("#content-body:contains('white gold'), #content-body:contains('yellow gold'), #content-body:contains('bracelet'), #content-body:contains('necklace'), #content-body:contains('charm'), #content-body:contains('pendant'), #content-body:contains('bangle'), #content-body:contains('diamond')").length) {
      $('#marketing').append('<img id="tradeandsaveimage" src="chrome-extension://oglkppenbgclfdedmogeodheocmeeafa/images/advertising/Trade-and-Save-Logo.jpg?w=803&h=603" width="804" height="604" />');
      $('#biic-item-type').text('Jewellery').addClass('bit-jewellery');
    } else if ($("#content-body:contains('dvd'), #content-body:contains('game disc'), #content-body:contains('game cartridge'), #content-body:contains('blu-ray disc')").length) {
      $('#marketing').append('<img id="tradeandsaveimage" src="chrome-extension://oglkppenbgclfdedmogeodheocmeeafa/images/advertising/Trade-and-Save-Logo.jpg?w=803&h=603" width="804" height="604" />');
      $('#biic-item-type').text('Game / DVD / Blu-Ray').addClass('bit-dvd');
    } else {
      $('#marketing').append('<img id="warrantyimage" src="chrome-extension://oglkppenbgclfdedmogeodheocmeeafa/images/advertising/Warranty-90-Day-Logo.jpg?w=803&h=603" width="804" height="604" /><img id="tradeandsaveimage" src="chrome-extension://oglkppenbgclfdedmogeodheocmeeafa/images/advertising/Trade-and-Save-Logo.jpg?w=803&h=603" width="804" height="604" />');
      $('#biic-item-type').text('General Stock').addClass('bit-general');
    }

    //    var descweightnext = $("#item-pre-description div p strong:contains('Weight')");
    //    if (descweightnext.length) {
    //      var bono = descweightnext.next('span').text();

    //    };
    //    $('#item-weight').text(bono);
  }, 500);
```

```css
div#biic-item-type {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  min-width: 86px !important;
  color: #fff;
  min-height: 16px;
  text-align: center
}

.bit-jewellery {
  background: #650080;
}

.bit-dvd {
  background: #6161a3;
}

.bit-general {
  background: #93102e;
}

#content-body {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="biic-item-type"></div>
<div id="content-body">
  <div id="item-weight"></div>
  <div id="header-split-left">
    <div id="item-title">
      This Is 40&nbsp;(000200195437)
    </div>
    <div id="item-category">
      DVD<br> </div>
  </div>
  <div id="header-split-right">
    <div id="item-product-number-copy">
      000200195437 </div>
  </div>
  <div id="the-body-stats">
    <div id="item-price">
      $6<sup>.00</sup><br> </div>
    <div id="description-paste-here">Product details: Item Number: 000200195437 Title: This Is 40 Box Set: No
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Frenchy on my live version of the code it doesnt fix it. Does it matter if the jquery is before or after the html dom?

Comment: It matters where you place your javascript and when you execute it, not only for jQuery but for every JS.

Comment: you could test by doing *console.log($("#content-body").text())* and you see what the result gives..

Comment: Thank you very much :-) I'm so glad it was something so simple and my understanding of the if's wasn't incorrect haha

Comment: glad to help you!!